# How to predict result with no label but a specific loss function

Tags: machine-learning, model, neural-network, deep-learning, unsupervised-learning

I've meet a problem recently. The target result are several columns(3 columns, only contain 1 or 0).

The target result could lead to a penalty function which could be used as a loss function for my model.

I've researched MLP\FFNN\SVM for these kind of problem which seems like to be unsupervised learning. But still got a little confused about how to apply these algorithm to the problem.

Cause there are a lot of examples of these algorithm seems to have a label for training.

So how could i tackle this problem? Any suggestion please?

Comment: You need to be way more specific, including code and approaches you have already tried.

Comment: The problem originally comes from this link, https://tianchi.aliyun.com/competition/information.htm?raceId=231609&_lang=en_US